# How do I copy all files that have been created or modified in the last 12 months?

Tags: shell-script, files, file-copy, timestamps, recursive

I would like to copy all the files created in the last 12 months to a new folder leaving behind everything else. Including sub folders.

Comment: Strictly speaking, this is almost impossible; most *nix systems don't keep track of files' creation date/times.  You can, however, look at when they were last changed or modified.

Comment: By “including sub folders”, do you mean that they should be copied, that files in them should be copied, or that they should be left behind?

Answer (score 3):

assuming you are ok with a flat destination folder (everything moved to the same place):

```
find /<top_level_folder> -type f -ctime -365 -exec cp -f {} /<new_folder_destination> \;
```

Comment: To get all files changed in the past year, use `-ctime -365` (or perhaps `-366`).

Comment: Updated. Thanks for catching my typo!

Comment: You could also use -mtime instead of -ctime to get all files modified in the last year

Comment: Well, yes; as I (somewhat obscurely) point out in a comment on the question, there are two different ways of interpreting the question.  They are not equivalent.

Comment: Gotcha.  And you're right, creation time is not kept.  The best you can do is ctime or mtime.

Comment: Thanks so much! Really appreciate it. Is there any way to save the folder structure as well?

Comment: `find /<source> -type f -ctime -365 -exec cp --parents \{\} /<destination>`

Comment: This question probably calls for `-mtime`, not `-ctime`. All kinds of things can change the ctime, such as changing permissions. If you want to find files created or modified in a certain date range, then the mtime is exactly right, under the reasonable assumption that it was not deliberately modified.